# Fill a 2-D array with all the factors of the numbers 1 to 1000 - java

Tags: java

I'm attempting to fill a 2D array with the numbers 1 to 1000 and then show all the factors of those numbers. I then need to find all the prime numbers in the same array and output them. Here's what I have so far, keep in mind that I was hoping to do every step in its own method then return them but have not got that far yet

```
int i = 0;
//int x = 0;
String primeNumber = "";

int[] [] factorArray = new int [1000] [];

for (int x = 0 ; x < 1000 ; x++)
{
    int remainder;
    int y;
    remainder = x % 2;
    y = x / 2;
    if (remainder != 0)
        System.out.println (x + ": " + "1, " + x);
    else if (remainder == 0)
        System.out.println (x + ": " + (y) + " , " + (y / 2) + " , " + " 1, " + x);
}

for (i = 1 ; i <= 1000 ; i++)
{

    int ctr = 0;
    for (int x = i ; x >= 1 ; x--)
    {
        if (i % x == 0){
            ctr = ctr + 1;
        }
    }
    if (ctr == 2)
    {
        primeNumber = primeNumber + i + " ";
    }

}

System.out.print ("Prime numbers from 1 - 1000 are : \n" + primeNumber);
```

Comment: So what is the issue? What are you having problems with?

Comment: The best way to do it is probably to write a short method `boolean isPrime(int number)` that checks if a number is prime, and call the method with every number in your array.

Comment: It does not seem to output the correct factors (or all the factors that is, it seems to do some of them) for each number when I run it.